# Live reverb effect to all audio linux

Tags: sound-effects, linux

Is it possible to apply live reverb or hall effect to all media that is played on linux, and how?

I know how to apply an effect to a single file but I want to add a reverb effect at a low-level that this is applied to all audio played on linux (browser, file, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your programs support pulseaudio (which is a standard presently), you can use [PulseEffects](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects). It has various effects available, including reverb.